# How to make a section with multiple numbers

Tags: tables, sectioning

I am creating tables with questions above them.
The answers have a unique ID and I want those IDs as the numbers for the section.

So for example:

12-14. On a scale of 1 to 3 how well can you do in LaTeX?

12. 1
13. 2
14. 3

So this above would be a table. I was thinking of adding labels for these questions, since there are single numbered ones, where \section would work perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve what you want using `enumerate`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using the `enumitem` package and the `enumerate` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\ref{q1firstitem}-\ref{q1lastitem}. Here is the question test
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1 \label{q1firstitem}
\item 2
\item 3 \label{q1lastitem}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{q2firstitem}-\ref{q2lastitem}. Here is the question test
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item 1 \label{q2firstitem}
\item 2
\item 3 \label{q2lastitem}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{q3firstitem}-\ref{q3lastitem}. Here is the question test
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item 1 \label{q3firstitem}
\item 2
\item 3 \label{q3lastitem}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```